# Reduce loop function

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have my program working but I'm just want to reduce it. This is only a small part of my code. I created a list for each zipcode to be assigned to different people. I want to reduce it because I currently have more than 20 lists assigned to the same amount of loop.

```
public class zipcodes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<Integer> pe1a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1547,1549 ));
        List<Integer> pe1b = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1606, 2458));
        List<Integer> pe1c = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3058, 2214, 3895));


        System.out.print("Enter the zipcode: ");
        int zipCodeNumber = 0;
        if (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
            zipCodeNumber = scnr.nextInt();
        } else {
          System.out.println("Please enter a valid ZipCode:");
        }


         for (Integer list : pe1a) if (zipCodeNumber == list) System.out.println("John");
         for (Integer list : pe1c) if (zipCodeNumber == list) System.out.println("Mark");
         for (Integer list : pe1d) if (zipCodeNumber == list) System.out.println("Luna");
```

Comment: Use a function?

Comment: Try `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

First at all I suggest to you to use a different data structure. Probably, I your case the best structure is an `HashMap`. The `HashMap` will allow you to have a single structure that hold all of your data.

```java
var zipcodeMap = new HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>>();

zipcodeMap.put("John", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1547,1549)));
zipcodeMap.put("Mark", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1606, 2458)));
zipcodeMap.put("Luna", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(3058, 2214, 3895)));
```

As you can see I put as a key of the `HashMap` a `String` object that hold the person name and as a value an `HashSet` that hold all the zip codes.

---

Now, that we have an `HashMap` we can easily replace all of these for-loops with a single `forEach()`.

```java
zipcodeMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
    if (v.contains(zipCodeNumber)) {
        System.out.println(k);
    }
});
```

In practice, the `forEach()` go trough each key-value pair and check if the `HashSet` contains the `zipCodeNumber`. If the `HashSet` contains the `zipCodeNumber` print the key (that's the `String` object that hold the person name).